# Returning QueryString in MVC 5 from ReturnUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

If user is going to, say, a landing page and is redirected to the login page, the url will look like this

https://OurDomain.com/HA5/Secure/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHA5%2FSecure%2FLanding%2F

I have tried every which way to get the query string

Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl") returns Nothing

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery doesn't include the query string.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long way round, but the only method I could find is the pass the value via jQuery

```
 var vPath = window.location.href;
jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ReturnURL", "Login")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { FullURL: vPath },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.indexOf('Invalid') >= 0) {
            //They got here from an old link
            window.location.href = '/secure/redirect/';
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ModalError(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    }



})
```

Controller (value saved as Session)

```
 <HttpPost()>
    Function ReturnURL(FullURL As String) As ActionResult
        Try
            If FullURL.Contains("ReturnUrl") Then
                Dim vID As Integer = FullURL.IndexOf("=")
                Dim vSub As String = FullURL.Substring(vID + 1)
                Session("ReturnUrl") = vSub.Replace("%2F", "/")
            End If

            Return Json("Success")
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex, 53, PageName)
            Return Json("Invalid")
        End Try
    End Function
```